# Is there a way to sort by the content inside an input box in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am making a data table where I shall show diffrent users information. I want to be able to sort for an example all the users by their firstname or lastname. I have used inputboxes becuse I also want to be able to edit the users information.

I have tried diffrent scripts from here on stackoverflow and other sites. But to no sucess. tried template and even copied straight off a working code but with out inputboxes then. I am also very new to Vue js only worked with it for 4 days.

```
<div id="app">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <!--Rubriker för tabellkolummer-->
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Förnamn</th>
                <th>Efternamn</th>
                <th>Telefonnummer</th>
                <th>E-postadress</th>
                <th>Behörighet</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(user,index) in users">
                <template v-if="user && user.editable">
                    <td><input type="text" v-model="user.uuid" class="input" disabled></td>
                    <td><input type="text" v-model="user.firstName" class="input"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" v-model="user.lastName" class="input"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" v-model="user.phone" class="input"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" v-model="user.email" class="input"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" v-model="user.jobTitle" class="input"></td>
                    <td><button class="button" @click="onUserClick(index)">Spara</button>
                        <button class="button" @click="tabortrad(index)">Ta bort rad</button></td>
                </template>
                <template v-else>
                    <td><input type="text" v-model="user.uuid" class="input" disabled></td>
                    <td><input type="text" v-model="user.firstName" class="input" disabled></td>
                    <td><input type="text" v-model="user.lastName" class="input" disabled></td>
                    <td><input type="text" v-model="user.phone" class="input" disabled></td>
                    <td><input type="text" v-model="user.email" class="input" disabled></td>
                    <td><input type="text" v-model="user.jobTitle" class="input" disabled></td>
                    <td><button class="button" @click="onUserClick(index)">Redigera</button>
                        <button class="button" @click="tabortrad(index)">Ta bort rad</button></td>
                </template>
            </tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th><button class="button is-pulled-right" @click='laggtillrad(users)'>Lägg till en rad</button></th>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<script>
    faker.locale = "sv";
    //Skapar slumpmässiga användardata
    let randomusers = [];
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        let uuid = faker.random.uuid();
        let firstName = faker.name.firstName();
        let lastName = faker.name.lastName();
        let phone = faker.phone.phoneNumber();
        let email = faker.internet.email();
        let jobTitle = faker.name.jobTitle();
        randomusers.push({ 'uuid': uuid, 'firstName': firstName, 'lastName': lastName, 'phone': phone, 'email': email, 'jobTitle': jobTitle });
    }
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            users: randomusers,
        },
        methods: {
            //Lägger till en rad längst ner i tabellen
            laggtillrad: function (event) {
                var nyrad = {
                    uuid: faker.random.uuid(),
                    firstName: faker.name.firstName(),
                    lastName: faker.name.lastName(),
                    phone: faker.phone.phoneNumber(),
                    email: faker.internet.email(),
                    jobTitle: faker.name.jobTitle(),
                };
                this.users.push(nyrad)
            },
            //Tar bort raden där användaren trycker på "Ta bort" knappen
            tabortrad: function (index) {
                this.users.splice(index, 1);
            },
            //Redigerar raden där användaren trycker på "Redigera" knappen och ersätts med en spara knapp
            onUserClick(index) {
                const changeUser = this.users[index];
                changeUser.editable = !changeUser.editable;
                this.$set(this.users, index, changeUser);
            }
        },
    })
</script>
```

I just want to be able to sort the users information. But think I must start all over again an use something called grid I think. But if someone can help me I will be very happy and maybe some off this code I have can come to use for someone else :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `sortedUsers` `computed` property that returns the sorted copy of `users` array and use it this way:
`<tr v-for="(user,index) in sortedUsers">` and

```
computed: {
    sortedUsers() {
        // Using destructuring to prevent users array in-place mutation
        return [...this.users].sort((userA, userB) => userA.firstName.localeCompare(userB.firstName))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer will give it a try :)
Have a nice day :)